# Computed column based on nullable columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I want to create a computed column that is the concatenation of several other columns.  In the below example, fulladdress is null in the result set when any of the 'real' columns is null.  How can I adjust the computed column function to take into account the nullable columns?

```
CREATE TABLE Locations
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [fulladdress]  AS (((([address]+[address2])+[city])+[state])+[zip]),
    [address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [address2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [city] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [state] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [zip] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gets messy pretty quick, but here's a start:

```
ISNULL(address,'')      + ' ' 
  + ISNULL(address2,'') + ' '
  + ISNULL(city,'')     + ' ' 
  + ISNULL(state,'')    + ' '
  + ISNULL(zip,'')
```

(If `isnull` doesn't work, you can try `coalesce`. If neither work, share what DMBS you're using.)

Comment: Thx, If i wanted to have the fields separated by commas (if the column has a value, append it followed by a comma and a space) how would i do it?

Comment: how about: select coalesce(address, '')
     + coalesce(', ' + address2, '')
     + coalesce(', ' + city, '')
     + coalesce(', ' + state, '')
     + coalesce(', ' + zip, '')
from Locations

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a full address column (which is a duplicate of other columns) stored  in your database unless you have a good reason. The correct way would be to construct the full address string in your queries. By creating the field dynamically you reduce redundancy in the table and you have one less column to maintain (which would need to be updated anytime any other column changes).

In your query you would do something like

```
SELECT CONCAT(ISNULL(address,''), ISNULL(address2,''), ISNULL(city,''), ISNULL(state,''), ISNULL(zip,'')) AS fulladdress FROM Locations;
```

The `CONCAT()` function performs concatenation and the `ISNULL()` gives you your string if it's not null or the second param (which was passed as '') if it is null

Comment: Thx. I wouldn't be persisting the fulladdress to the DB (since it is a computed column in the table definition), so there would be no reason to update it.