# Computed Column (COALESCE vs CASE vs ISNULL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, coalesce, calculated-columns

I posted a similar question a while back and now as I need to update this code, I am back to ask a follow-on question.  Previous question is here:
[Computed column based on nullable columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590891/computed-column-based-on-nullable-columns)

My data (`Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, Country`) may have incomplete information.  I.e. I can't be guaranteed that anything other than `State` and `Country` columns will have data.

I would like to have a computed columns for `FullAddress`.

Previously, I used `COALESCE`, which worked great if all fields are filled in.  Now, as the data requirements have been relaxed, this is no longer an option (because we end with repeated commas in the `FullAddress`).  Here is what I have been using previously (*note, I'm just working with SELECT statements here for ease of use - will convert into a computed columns "alter table add" statement once I have something that works for all cases*):

```
SELECT (((((COALESCE([Address1],'')
    + COALESCE(', '+[Address2],''))
    + COALESCE(', '+[City],''))
    + COALESCE(', '+[State],''))
    + COALESCE(', '+[Zip],''))
    + COALESCE(', '+[Country],'')) AS FullAddress
FROM Locations
```

Now, I have put together an alternative using `CASE`, but it still doesn't work for the edge case where `Address1 is NULL` (the problem is that the `FullAddress` will have ', ' as the first two characters)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [Address1] IS NOT NULL THEN [Address1] ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN [Address2] IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + [Address2] ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN [City] IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + [City] ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN [State] IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + [State] ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN [Zip] IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + [Zip] ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN [Country] IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + [Country] ELSE '' END
        AS [FullAddress]
FROM Locations
```

I'm a little stuck at this point.  Any recommendations what to try next?

Comment: My question is: how do I construct the statement such that in the case of missing data (e.g. missing Address1), the FullAddress computed column doesn't start with ', '

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use this pattern:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(Address1 + ', ', '')
    + ISNULL(Address2 + ', ', '')
    + ISNULL(City + ', ', '')
    -- ....
    AS FullAddress
```

The result of concation `NULL + ', '` is `NULL` => `Address1 + ', '` will be NULL or valid address => `ISNULL(Address1 + ', ', '')` will be empty string or valid address.

Comment: Yup, makes sense now that I look at it - add NULL to anything in SQL and it stays NULL.

Comment: I don't know how "relaxed" your data requirements are. If e.g. you only have data on column `City`, your output will have an extra `, ` at the end. Maybe you should consider using a User Defined Function.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT STUFF(
         COALESCE(', ' + Address1, '') + COALESCE(', ' + Address2, '') + ...
         1,
         2,
         ''
       ) AS FullAddress
FROM Locations
```

The concatenated string will either be empty or start with `,`  (a comma and a space). `STUFF()` will remove the first two characters and return the rest of the string.